# Caching friendly_id plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, friendly-id

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
end
```

What is the most efficient method to store the slugs within the 'products' table.
I have complex find queries, and the joins with the 'slugs' table give me performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I know this is an old question, but just wanted to note, for others that may stumble across this:

The code snippet in the question is from FriendlyId 3.x in which case you would add a column to your table (call it anything except for `slug` ... I prefer to use `cached_slug`) as a string and update the model to show

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true, :cache_column => 'cached_slug'
end
```

As of friendly_id 4.x, you simply just add a `slug` column as a `string` to the table, and use the new syntax:

eg:

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged
end
```

There are a whole bunch of options and ways to get the most out of friendly_id including historical records (to avoid 404s) etc ...

More information: http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/frames

Answer (score 1):

Friendly_id now has built-in slug caching.